# Unable to load model checkpoint to continue training,Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I'am trying to load model to continue training but i kepp getting error

> NotFoundError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for ./drive/My Drive/DLSRL/Model/
>
> [[Node: save/RestoreV2_81 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2_81/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_81/shape_and_slices)]]
>
> [[Node: save/RestoreV2_3/_189 = _Recvclient_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_396_save/RestoreV2_3", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]]
>
> Caused by op 'save/RestoreV2_81', defined at:
>     File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
>       "**main**", mod_spec)

my folder structure
model contain checkpoint,03-27-09-15_epoch_29.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001,03-27-09-15_epoch_29.ckpt.index,03-27-09-15_epoch_29.ckpt.meta

Here is the code

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./drive/My Drive/DLSRL/Model/03-27-09-15_epoch_39.ckpt.meta')
    g = tf.get_default_graph()
    with g.as_default():


      model = Model(config, embeddings, label_dict.size(), g)
      sess = tf.Session(graph=g, config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True,
                                                       log_device_placement=False))
      saver.restore(sess,'./drive/My Drive/DLSRL/Model/')
      #sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
      ckpt_saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=config.max_epochs)
      for epoch in range(39,config.max_epochs):
          # save chckpoint from which to load model
          path = runs_dir / "{}_epoch_{}.ckpt".format(time_of_init, epoch)
          ckpt_saver.save(sess, str(path))
          print('Saved checkpoint.')
          evaluate(dev_data, model, sess, epoch, global_step)
          x1, x2, y = shuffle_stack_pad(train_data, config.train_batch_size)
          epoch_start = time.time()
          for x1_b, x2_b, y_b in get_batches(x1, x2, y, config.train_batch_size):
              feed_dict = make_feed_dict(x1_b, x2_b, y_b, model, config.keep_prob)
              if epoch_step % LOSS_INTERVAL == 0:
                  # tensorboard
                  run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.NO_TRACE)
                  scalar_summaries = sess.run(model.scalar_summaries,
                                     feed_dict=feed_dict,
                                     options=run_options)
                  model.train_writer.add_summary(scalar_summaries, global_step)
                  # print info
                  print("step {:>6} epoch {:>3}: loss={:1.3f}, epoch sec={:3.0f}, total hrs={:.1f}".format(
                      epoch_step,
                      epoch,
                      epoch_loss_sum / max(epoch_step, 1),
                      (time.time() - epoch_start),
                      (time.time() - global_start) / 3600))
              loss, _ = sess.run([model.nonzero_mean_loss, model.update], feed_dict=feed_dict)

              epoch_loss_sum+= loss
              epoch_step += 1
              global_step += 1
          epoch_step = 0
          epoch_loss_sum = 0.0
```

Can you please suggest fixes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify checkpoint to restore. Change to:

```
saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./drive/My Drive/DLSRL/Model/'))
```